# How to avoid nintex workflow sending email notification when a new folder is added to a library?

Tags: email, sharepoint, notifications, nintex-workflow

I have a documents library where mainly pdf and doc are uploaded. I have also got a nintex workflow running behind this library.

The workflow sends an email notification to users every time a new document is uploaded. However it is also sending emails when a new folder is created.

Is there any way we can get nintex to NOT send emails when a folder is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a check at the start of the workflow for content type.. If folder end wf. Or goto workflow settings and put a conditional event on create. To only start wf if content type = document

Comment: Yes that was my initial thought but when I went to implement the idea I was not sure on how to actually set the condition so wf will end if 'content type = folder'. Do you know how this can be done?